# Why is the hinge loss not differentiable? Why can we find its subgradients?

Tags: loss-functions

I want to understand why the hinge loss isn't differentiable. I see that it has a corner which would make it not differentiable there, but then why can we take its subgradients? As far as I know, the $max \left\{0,1-y_it_i \right\}$ have corners too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4608/gradient-of-hinge-loss