# Binary Hinge Loss. Choosing best model

Tags: machine-learning, svm, loss-functions

I was reviewing the answer to the question about the ["Gradient of Hinge Loss" here:](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/96253/20257) and noticed that one of the answers proposed returning of averaged weights in function:

```
def grad_descent(): 
...
return np.sum(ws,1)/np.size(ws,1)
```

I m curious if there is any special reason for averaging weights? Why not to find best weights by using the validating set on each epoch?